# TypeError: result.push is not function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these two functions, both generate a range from start to end inclusive, where start and end are integers. They look like this:

```
function range(start, end) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(1,5));
//Expected output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function functional_range(start, end) {
  function functional_range_helper(result, strt, nd) {
    if (strt > nd) return [];
    if (strt === nd) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return functional_range_helper(result.push(strt), strt + 1, nd);
    }
  }
  return functional_range_helper([], start, end);
}

console.log(functional_range(1,5));
//Expected output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The first one runs perfectly. The second errors out with "TypeError: result.push is not a function." I don't understand why this is happening because I'm passing an array as the first argument to the helper function and using the correct parameter name inside the helper function to reference it. It is an array, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length, not the array. So `functional_range_helper(result.push(strt), strt + 1, nd)` is passing a number as the first argument instead of the array.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's not the behavior I expected. I guess I've just learned another place to look before ask questions, at least. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is .push() doesn't return the array, it returns the length. So the return value of "result.push(strt)" will be an integer, not an array like you are expecting.

To fix, push the value in separate step like:

```
function functional_range(start, end) {
    function functional_range_helper(result, strt, nd) {
        if (strt > nd) return [];
        if (strt === nd) {
            return result;
       } else {
           result.push(strt);
           return functional_range_helper(result, strt + 1, nd);
       }
   }
    return functional_range_helper([], start, end);
}
```

Comment: the return type of .push is undefined.

Comment: "Returns: The new length property of the object upon which the method was called." see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: yes, sorry its my mistake. it returns integer. Thank you very much.